# Share an In-App Purchase between iOS and OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase

I noticed Bear Notes has a subscription in-app purchase that if you buy it on iOS it also unlocks it on Mac OS X, and vice-versa.

I've seen a few clues out there as to how to do it, such as using the App Store receipt, but I don't know how Bear was able to identify that I'm the same user on my Mac as I am on iOS.

If it was using a receipt, then it would have to take the receipt from iOS, send it to the server, but then know do you fetch the receipt for me when I'm on my Mac?

As far as I remember, I didn't have to identify myself in either app.

Comment: Most likely using your iCloud to identify you. If I'm not mistaken Bear says they use iCloud to sync your data anyway, so I'm pretty sure that's how they know who you are. As far as the store receipt, they could be using that, or they could have just saved an entry on their servers (or in CloudKit, who knows) indicating you purchased a subscription.

Comment: @PJayRushton I believe you are correct, I was curious so I installed and purchased the IAP. The only network traffic from the app was to play.itunes.apple.com (to make the purchase). I initially thought they are using [Universal Purchasing](https://developer.apple.com/support/universal-purchase/) but bundleId's are different and it seems to be only supported between tvOS and iOS. So yes, I think you're right, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

First, about the Bear app, it identify you by AppleId. With the same AppleId, it can share every informations.

Then, about the receipt, I don't know if Bear implement it and verify it again on Mac or iPhone but when you purchase something successfully, you need to send some informations to your server. Not to mention to receipt, these informations can unlock your features anywhere you login with the same AppleId.

Answer (score 0):

It easy, you just make application for macOS and iOS
https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/bundleId/

And make some In-App Purchase.
In both platform you try restore purchase
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/offering_completing_and_restoring_in-app_purchases

And it shared purchase between platforms (iOS, macOS, tvOS) & user devices with Apple Id.

More Information about In-App
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase